# how generic types are inferred automatically in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, lambda

The Simple Html.HiddenFor signature is below.

```
public static MvcHtmlString HiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression);
```

And the usage is simple @Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.PropertyName)

My question is, how the generic types are inferred automatically in MVC. I used some generic methods with the same argument types but when I don't specify the type, it says generic types cannot be inferred automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify a model for your view like this:

```
@model TModel
```

You basically create a view that derives from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>`.
Now if you look at the implementation of this class you will find the following code:

```
 public abstract class WebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage
    {
        private ViewDataDictionary<TModel> _viewData;

        public new AjaxHelper<TModel> Ajax { get; set; }

        public new HtmlHelper<TModel> Html { get; set; }

        public new TModel Model
        {
            get { return ViewData.Model; }
        }
```

Here you can see that it has an HtmlHelper property:

```
 public new HtmlHelper<TModel> Html { get; set; }
```

So basically, generic types here are inferred automatically because all helpers that you using in this View are extensions of `HtmlHelper<TModel>` (Where `TModel` is the model that you specified earlier)

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. So what I extracted is when you specify type of generic at class level, then you don't need to specify with every function. This is what MVC is doing.